# Calling a public method from Main()

Tags: c#, methods, console

How would I call the `GetDFT()` method in the following program?

```
namespace Lott_CSC445_Project6
{
    class Program
    {    
        ... // declarations removed for brevity

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ... // some code

            GetDFT() // <<< Call the method here

            ... // more code
        }

        public void GetDFT()
        {
            ... // method body removed for brevity
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a **real question**. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: make that method static and you can just call it - it doesn't use any non-static state - better yet refactor all of this to use separate classes

Comment: When asking a question, please only post the _relevant_ bits of code. You have thrown in the whole kitchen sink here when a small bit of the class would have done. Please see [sscce](http://sscce.org/) for good  guidelines.

Comment: You should start from here: [Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173109.aspx), [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is not `static`, so it is an *instance* method of `Program`.

That means you need an instance of `Program` to call it on.

Alternatively, make the method `static`.

Comment: If I make it static then the boolMatrix function in the GetDFT will not work.

Comment: @JLott - For pretty much the same reasons.